# Curl read the word script in url as a command

Tags: curl, cmd

all.

When i run this curl command

```html
curl -o prc_%id_proc%.txt --basic --user admin:admin -k "https://myurl.com:1001/nest/lmv/wle/v10/prc/%id_proc%?action=js&script=tw.local.Proc&parts=all"
```

The thing is that it removes the "js&script=tw.local.Proc&parts=all" part because it thinks that script is a procedure and return the full file instead of the section im looking for.

How can i remove this?

Comment: Are you looking for `--data-urlencode`? Looks like your url isn't being encoded properly. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86729/any-way-to-encode-the-url-in-curl-command for more information.

Comment: Thanks @nbokmans, he still ignores the rest of the url. maybe im doing something wrong, going to search a little more, thanks